# Ansible using systemd instead of service module

Tags: ansible, devops

I'm just getting my feet wet with Ansible 2.2 and Debops and I've run into the following problem. I have a host `test-host` to which I deployed a MySQL server (using [geerlingguy.mysql](https://github.com/geerlingguy/ansible-role-mysql)).

The role uses the following handler to restart the service:

```
---
- name: restart mysql
  service: "name={{ mysql_daemon }} state=restarted sleep=5"
```

which, I thought, uses Ansibles [service module](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/service_module.html) to restart the server. However, that fails:

```
unsupported parameter for module: sleep
```

So just to rule out any weirdness with that custom role, I've tried to execute the module directly like so:

```
ansible test-host -b -m service -a 'name=mysql sleep=5 state=restarted'
```

with the same result.

Running Ansible with more verbose output shows (among other things):

```
Running systemd
Using module file /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible-2.2.0-py2.7.egg/ansible/modules/core/system/systemd.py
```

So it appears that the `systemd` module is used instead of `service` (looking into the module shows that it is indeed [aliased to `service`](https://github.com/ansible/ansible-modules-core/blob/devel/system/systemd.py#L33)). And, lo and behold, `systemd` does not support the `sleep` parameter.

How to fix this?

Comment: So in the mean time there are a couple things you can do. The first is to use the latest supported release which is `v2.1.0.0-1`. The second is to raise an issue on https://github.com/ansible/ansible-modules-core/issues if it does not already exist since this is clearly not expected behavior.

Comment: Issue created: https://github.com/ansible/ansible-modules-core/issues/3897

Comment: Related: If you install the systemd service on an upstart-based system like Ubuntu 14.04, ansible will use the systemd module instead of the service module, causing pain.  https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/19030

Comment: Voting to close. This issue was fixed 6 months ago by [commit 16720](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/pull/16720). There's no reason for the question to remain open and unanswered.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the underlying issue has been fixed several months ago.

Answer (score 3):

You can workaround it by adding another step in your playbook like this:

```
- name: restart mysql
  service: "name={{ mysql_daemon }} state=restarted"
  register: mysql_service

- name: pause after mysql restart
  pause: "seconds=5"
  when: mysql_service.changed
```